# Código para reemplazar carácteres en un archivo de texto

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python. Necesito ayuda para programar un código con el cual, puedas seleccionar un carácter para ser reemplazado por otro también seleccionable en un archivo de texto.

> ```
> pregunta1 = input("Carácter para reemplazar : ")
> pregunta2 = input("Nuevo carácter : ")
>
> contenido = open("Archivo.txt", "r").read()
> contenido.replace(pregunta1, pregunta2)
> ```

Este es mi código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mi interpretación del problema :**

Posiblemente lo que búsques es reemplazar todos los carácteres de un archivo de texto para posteriormente reescribir el mismo archivo con un cambio en cuanto a los carácteres, si ese es el caso una solución en base a mi lógica sería utilizar la función "open()" y asignar dos términos, el primero sería la ruta del archivo y el segundo sería la especificación, en este caso "w" para reescribir el archivo. Posteriormente escribimos el contenido reemplazado dentro del archivo y finalmente utilizamos el método "close()" para liberar recursos.

**Código en base a mi propuesta :**

> ```
> pregunta1 = input("Carácter para reemplazar : ")
> pregunta2 = input("Nuevo carácter : ")
>
> contenido = open("Archivo.txt", "r").read()
> contenido = contenido.replace(pregunta1, pregunta2)
>
> with open("Archivo.txt", "w") as archivo:
>     archivo.write(contenido)
>     archivo.close()
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y describí cómo esto responde a la pregunta. Puede que la respuesta sea obvia para vos, no así para otros usuarios que lleguen a tener un problema similar más adelante. Leé [answer].